# How can Hadoop job kill by itself

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way to kill a Hadoop job itself or send a signal to kill it.
I've read the Configuration settings from jobConf where it says that if a user specify the wrong settings I need to kill the job or throw an error, since map/reduce **config** method does not allow throwing an exception.

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {
    System.out.println("Inside config start processing");
     try {

            String strFileName =  job.get("hadoop.rules");
            LoadFile(strFileName );
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        //Here i need to write code to kill job
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the configure() method, just throw a RuntimeException.

Better yet, if possible, you're better off performing your validation step before the job is run.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the state into a boolean variable called `kill` and evaluate the variable inside the map step and then throw an `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but in that case the codition will be check for each record processed by map.