# How to kill running Job from Mapper in Hadoop 2 (wanted: reference to running Job object)

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Several stackoverflow entries have addressed this question but none quite seem to nail it. I want logic whereby even if one task on one node fails, I kill the entire job before it finishes. A good strategy seems to be to get a reference to the running job, then call job.killJob() from within the particular Mapper.map() call that failed. This seems much easier than writing a YarnClient and killing the job that way. And easier, again, than somehow getting the job reference from the driver class, checking if any tasks have failed, and calling job.killJob() if true.

One approach to killing is suggested by [1]: [How to abort a MR job inside a mapper (or a reducer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998470/how-to-abort-a-mr-job-inside-a-mapper-or-a-reducer)

But as one reader comments, it does not seem possible in Hadoop 2 to get a reference to the running job from a JobID. Another approach is to call new Job(context.getConfiguration()).killJob(). But will this work? I want an instance to the running job, not to a new Job instance. If this new Job object instance would nevertheless point to the existing, running job, that might work. But is that the case?

Other pages, such as [How can Hadoop job kill by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055296/how-can-hadoop-job-kill-by-itself)   recommend throwing an exception from within Mapper code. But this would seem not to force rapid shutdown of the application, and in any event might only shut down execution on a particular node.

Comment: I wrote 'If this new Job object instance would nevertheless point to the existing, running job, that might work.'    killJob() called on the new Job instance does seem to work. But this enables kill only from within Mapper code. I can get a list of TaskReports from inside map() code, but if say a node machine fails it will be hard to pick up the failure. Best would be to have some sort of watcher code that would monitor the entire job from outside.

Comment: Should it be required that the whole job fail if any task or part of the job fails, another technique is defined at the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452565/hadoop-how-can-i-prevent-failed-tasks-from-making-the-whole-job-fail